# ¿Cómo abrir una imagen desde el ordenador con python?

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

Estoy trabajando en mi primera interfaz en Python con TKinter orientado a clases. Mi asignación es una interfaz de facturación de un supermercado.

Parte de la asignación es la creación de un nuevo producto a ofrecerse en el inventario, y para ésto de supone que el programa debe pedirle a usuario que seleccione de entre el ordenador una imágen para que se muestre junto a la información del producto y no tengo idea de por dónde abordar eso. Cualquier ayuda o consejo sobre por dónde empezar me será muy útil.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aca no se brinda consejo, porque se considera basado en opiniones... intentalo y cuando tengas un problema concreto con gusto te ayudamos!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.